# PHP ODBC MDB Access on a Cloud Server

Tags: php, ms-access, odbc, jboss-mdb

Hopefully quick question....

I have a .MDB file stored on my webserver and I'm trying to connect to it.
I have no way of "registering" it with a name in ODBC.

Is the only way to connect to it by specifying the absolute page of the .mdb file?

> $mdbFilename = "./db/Scora.mdb";
>   $connection =
>   odbc_connect("Driver={Microsoft Access
>   Driver
>   (*.mdb)};Dbq=$mdbFilename","","");
>
> if (!$connection) {   echo "Couldn't
>   make a connection!";  }
>
> $sql = "SELECT ID FROM
>   ScoraRegistrations"; $sql_result =
>   odbc_prepare($connection,$sql);
>   odbc_execute($sql_result); 
>   odbc_result_all($sql_result,"border=1");
>   odbc_free_result($sql_result); 
>   odbc_close($connection);

It never connects.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

1. try an absolute filename.
2. see if the mdb driver is installed on your server. If it's a unix server, chances are ... low.